# Semantics of generic in Java's Comparator.comparing method

Tags: java, generics

While going through the JAVA doc, I found following signature of comparing method

```
 static <T,U extends Comparable<? super U>>
Comparator<T> comparing(Function<? super T,? extends U> keyExtractor)
```

I understand that U should be comparable but what is the signification of using

```
Comparable<? super U>
```

instead of using just `Comparable<U>`

Similarly, What is the significance of using `Function<? super T,? extends U> keyExtractor`
over `Function<T,U> keyExtractor`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Comment: @Aominè I disagree. That question is about how to differentiate when to use which, among `extends` and `super`, whereas this question is about the "why".

Comment: @Sweeper but then your answer starts and ends with PECS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The is using the principle of Producer Extends Consumer Super (PECS).

Basically, PECS says that if a generic parameter is used as a parameter type of a method, it should use contravariance i.e. `super`. If it is used as a return value type, it should use covariance i.e. `extends`.

`U` is constrained to `extend Comparable<? super U>`. Here, `super` is used to achieve contravariance for `U`. So even if `U` is `String`, you can pass in a `Comparable<Object>`.

The `Function` parameter type is `Function<? super T,? extends U>` to achieve contravariance on `T` (consumer, as is used in parameter type of `Function`) and covariance on `U` (as is used in return value type of `Function`). This enables you to pass a `Function<Object, String>` even if `T` is `String` and `U` is `Object`.

The significance is that without `extends` or `super`, this is called invariance. This means that you have to pass instances of exactly the generic parameter types `T` and `U`, which reduces flexibility.

To learn more about PECS, visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).

Answer (score 2):

Usually it means that a super class might implement `Comparator`.  Like for example if `Number` implements `Comparable`, the a `List<Integer>.sort(null)` is OK, because the comparable is on a super class of Integer.

With out that, the comparator would required to be `Comparable<Integer>` and since the comparable is actually `Comparable<Number>` it wouldn't work.